# Can Win32 popup menus respond to the scroll wheel?

Tags: winapi, menu, mousewheel

Say I have a bog-standard Win32 popup menu, and it's taller than the screen. It sprouts an up arrow at the top and a down arrow at the bottom, so the user can scroll through its items.

It's it possible at all for such a menu to response to Mouse Wheel scrolling? Scroll wheel events are sent to the focused control, which is not the menu, so what typically happens is that a text editor behind the menu scrolls instead.

Update: That is, is there a way for me to route the scroll wheel events, or some message I can send to a popped-open menu to programmatically scroll it up or down a notch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hack together something yourself, but it wouldn't be a Win32 menu.  It's not part of the UI standard.

The reason this is true is probably what you already stated; the Win32 menu cannot receive the focus.

Answer (score 0):

Can you collapse menu in some way? Office hides less-used menus and provide a menu item to load them when necessary. if not you can write your own paging like the start menu does.

Comment: There's no nested structure to the items in the menu, unfortunately. Typically it won't be so big, but then sometimes it will.